# Guzzle 6 fopen error after 120 secondds

Tags: php, vagrant, php-ini, guzzle6

I have a script in php that uses Guzzle 6 to make a very long GET petition to an API like this:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => $this->app_config["domains"][$this->service_name]);
$response = $client->request('GET', $uri);
return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

I supose that the problem comes when the petition reaches about 120 seconds. The error says:

```
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(.......): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
[file] /vagrant/Orchestrator/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
[line] 312
```

I launch this script in a vagrant box with php 5.6 and php.ini configured with max_execution_time = 0.

The fact is that in my local machine with the same php.ini and php version it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can not connect to the host from your Vagrant box. And 120 seconds is a default timeout (check `default_socket_timeout` value in PHP settings).

So check the connection to outside world from the Vagrant box.

Comment: finally changing default_socket_timeout and setting allow_url_fopen = 1 insted of "On" seems te fix the problem.